# Group by and Order by function in sqlite3 to aggregate substr values of a column in Python

Tags: python, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, python-itertools

I have written the following code below to select a range between 200 and 300, but doesn't seem to work, ORDER BY seems to return all values and GROUP BY returns only one value outside of the range specified. Can anyone shed a light on this? Below are the column names. I would also like to aggregate all exchanges, COUNT didn't seem to work, not sure if itertools is the right tool for the job.

first_name, last_name, company, address, city, county, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web

```
    import os, csv, json, re
    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect('US_500.sqlite')
    conn.text_factory = str
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    reader = cursor.execute ("SELECT phone1 FROM SampleData  GROUP BY substr(phone1, 5) BETWEEN 200 AND 300")


    tabledata = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in (tabledata):
        print str(row)

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `WHERE substr(...` instead of `GROUP BY substr(...`.

`GROUP BY` makes a query into an aggregate query.

Comment: GROUP BY needs to be included to group like kind values. I've already tried WHERE no luck...